# Track usage time of all apps and power button pressing with iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, events, button, time

I need to write an app that should monitor the usage time of all apps that are currently running on iOS(1).

The app should also be able to track how often the user uses the on / off button at a specific time frame (2).

Can you help me how to do this with iOS. Are there already existing open source solutions?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: It's not possible on a non-jailbroken iPhone running iOS 9 or later. Apple doesn't allow 3rd party apps to monitor other apps. There used to be ways to do this in older OS's, but Apple shut those down.

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Same as sandbox, I don't think you can do it. Apple doesn't allow monitoring other apps. If u want to do, prob have to jailbreak.

Comment: Thanks, i want to run it without jailbreak so i see it is not possible

Comment: I agree, I don't think Apple will approve to be accessed the Siri in the background